# ARM64 - Linux kernel Image to Bare Metal

Tags: linux-kernel

**Background**

I have built Linux kernel for ARM64. Got two main files as a result - "Image" in the boot folder and "vmlinux" in the root folder of the source tree. I am using U-Boot boot loader. Using the "fatload" command of U-Boot, I can load the Image file (and the DTB) to memory. Then using the "booti" command, I can successfully boot the kernel. (My understanding is that, "booti" command knows how to interpret the Image file)

**Question**

I wish to convert Image/vmlinux to a bare metal binary that can be launched from another program. The execution sequence would be like this-

1. Board starts and U-Boot is executed. From U-Boot terminal, using the "fatload" command the DTB and "my bare metal program" can be loaded to memory.

**using *some mechanism* the bare metal code of Image/vmlinux can be loaded to memory. May I know what is the best suited method for this? (or for converting Image/vmlinux to bare metal code)**

2. Using "go" command of U-Boot, "my bare metal program" can be executed.
3. From "my bare metal program" the control is to be transferred to the kernel.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The **Image** file is already a standalone binary image file. But the Linux kernel has specific startup requirements that the `go` command does not perform. Hence the need for a `booti` (and similar) commands. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/arm64/booting.rst

Comment: Would be far simpler to have a boot command that executes a "*bare metal program*" and returns to U-Boot, which then proceeds to boot the Linux kernel. IOW **you're asking an XY question**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ARM64 boot requirements. As per the document the "Image" file has 64 byte header. The first 8 bytes of the header are u32 code0;/* Executable code */  u32 code1;/* Executable code */  ...   I am surprised to see the DOS MZ header in the Image file got as my build output `

Comment: $linux/arch/arm64/boot$ xxd Image | [ADDRESS]00000000: [HEX]4d5a 0091 [ASCII]MZ..` This made me to think that "Image" file has a non executable header. (Would this file execute?) Some insight please?

Comment: The "MZ" is there because the kernel was built with UEFI runtime support enabled (`CONFIG_EFI`). See the `add x13, x18, #0x16` instruction in [5.10 arch/arm64/kernel/head.S](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S?h=v5.10). (Note: the magic number changed a bit in v5.11, but the first two bytes are still "MZ".)